# How to draw flowchart in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-graphdrawing, flow-charts

I want to draw a flowchart like this :
[image]

But it did not work out for me especially for arrows. When connecting the arrows between nodes they cross each other. 
[image]
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H] 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]
\node (start) [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!30] at (0,3) {Start};

\node (x1) [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!30] at (4,4) {X1};
\node (x2) [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!30] at (4,3) {X2};
\node (x3) [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!30] at (4,2) {X3};

\node (y1) [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!30] at (8,4) {Y1};
\node (y2) [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!30] at (10,3) {Y2};
\node (y3) [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!30] at (12,2) {Y3};

\node (end) [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!30] at (6,0) {END};

\draw[-latex] (start.east) -> (x1.west);
\draw[-latex] (start.east) -> (x2.west);
\draw[-latex] (start.east) -> (x3.west);

\draw[loosely dotted] (x1.east) -> (y1.west);
\draw[loosely dotted] (x2.east) -> (y2.west);
\draw[loosely dotted] (x3.east) -> (y3.west);


\draw[-latex] (y1.south) -> (y2.north);
\draw[-latex] (y1.south) -> (y3.north);
\draw[-latex] (y2.south) -> (y3.north);

\draw[densely dotted] (y1.south) -> (end.north);
\draw[densely dotted] (y2.south) -> (end.north);
\draw[densely dotted] (y3.south) -> (end.north);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Test.}
\label{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How you can prevent arrows from crossing? But they also cross in the referenced picture! Also, the layout in your example is different, is this intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redrawn your image with considering your nodes' style:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm and -3mm,
every node/.style = {draw=black, rounded corners, fill=gray!30, 
                     minimum width=2cm, minimum height=0.5cm,
                     align=center},
every path/.style = {draw, -latex}
                        ]
\node (start) {Start};
%
\node (y1) [below  left=of start]       {Y1}; 
\node (y2) [below right=of y1.east]     {Y2};
\node (y3) [below right=of y2.east]     {Y3};
%
\node (x1) [right=12mm of y3.east |- y1]{X1};
\node (x2) [right=12mm of y3.east |- y2]{X2};
\node (x3) [right=12mm of y3.east]      {X2};
%
\node (end) [below=21mm of y2 |- y3]    {END};
%
\node [dashed, fill=none, fit=(x1) (x3)] {};
%%
\draw   (start) -| (y1);
\draw   (start) -- (y2);
\draw   (start) -| (y3);
%
\draw   (x1) edge (y1)
        (x2) edge (y2)
        (x3)  to  (y3);
%
    \begin{scope}[densely dashed]
\draw   (y1) |- ([shift={(-5mm,9mm)}] end.north) -- ([xshift=-5mm] end.north);
\draw   (y2) -- (end);
\draw   (y3) |- ([shift={( 5mm,9mm)}] end.north) -- ([xshift= 5mm] end.north);
%
\draw   (y1 |- y2) -- (y2);
\draw[transform canvas={yshift= 1mm}]  (y1 |- y3) -- (y3);
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=-1mm}]  (y2 |- y3) -- (y3);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Nodes' style for all nodes are defined in `tikzpicture` options with `every node/.style`. For node positioning is used TikZ library `positioning`. Dashed line around nodes `X` is done by node with dashed line, in which are fitted nodes `X`.